# Artifactory RPM virtual repository with yum client

Tags: artifactory, rpm, yum

I am using Artifactory 5.4.6. I have created a virtual RPM repository, including a local RPM repository and multiple remote repositories.

How can i configure YUM client to use this virtual repository?

Resources Referred: 
1. [User-Guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/RPM+Repositories) 
2. [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZvwamCJR-Q)

Answer (score 1):

Create file `/etc/yum.repos.d/your.repo` with content:

```
[yourid]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
name=your private repo
baseurl=https://url.to.your.repository/                
skip_if_unavailable=True                                                                                                
enabled=1
```

There can be more options. See `man dnf.conf` (they are mostly the same for DNF and YUM).

Comment: it doesn't work. It gives error stating repo doesn't have repodata directory. As it is a virtual repo, it will have many repodata directories in subdirectries, no repodata is at top level. BTW thanks for reply.